# Background Image Makes Site Hard To Read

Tags: feature-request

I'm having a hard time reading the questions and answers because of the paper(?) background image.

Would it be possible to change this to a solid color to make it easier on *my* eyes?

E.g. http://math.stackexchange.com has a background image as well but uses a white background for text.

Comment: You should try [Theme Switcher](http://stackapps.com/questions/2808/stackexchange-theme-switcher). It's a little userscript that changes the theme of the site to the theme of any other SE site. The beta theme all betas share is very simple and clean, and imho is the easier one on the eyes (my eyes, that is).

Comment: Interesting. However I'm often browsing from different VMs and tablets so I don't really have that option.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a bookmark in chrome (not sure if other browsers allow arbitrary javascript execution from a bookmark) with this content, it'll kill the background when you click it:

```
javascript:(function(){$('body').css('background-image','url()');$('.container').css('background-image','url()');})();
```

Or better yet.. If you like SO's look you can use this:

```
$('link[href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/programmersmeta/all.css?v=f078930b28c8"]').attr('href','http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=0f0c93534e2b');
```

and it will change the entire theme of P.SE to SO's, or you can try any other by swapping the v=blablabla query string variable.

Comment: The problem is that I would have to set this up for every browser and then click the bookmarklet every time I click a link to another question.

Comment: @chris then, tough.